# Lock wait timeout exceeded when modifying users table used by JdbcUserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working on a REST service which uses spring-security and oAuth tokens to authenticate users. After registration, users are supposed to click a link I send to their email within one week after registration. If they fail to do that, I'll block the account (update users set enabled=0 where email=...).

Now, when they verify the email, I'll unblock the account (similar query). For that, I've got a simple method:

```
@Transactional
@GetMapping("/email-verification")
public String verification(...) {
    ...
    dbServer.createSqlUpdate("update users set enabled = 1 where email = :email");
    ...
}
```

Note that non-authenticated users can do this request. (Not sure if that's important).

Till recently, I didn't realize that the default datasource configuration uses autocomit and this code worked fine. Because I actually want to use transactions properly, I added this to the configuration:

`spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=false`

Since then, I'm getting this exception every time the code tries to modify the users table:

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

My best bet is that spring security is holding an open transaction with (at least) read lock for the users table for the duration of the request. When I try to modify the table, my transaction will never get that lock because I'm doing that within the same request.

Am I correct? If so, what is the proper way of modifying the users table? I'd say Spring-security should offer methods for disabling and enabling user account but I didn't find them.

Thanks for any hint.